# Problem installing Latex

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, latex

when I tried to install Latex on my machine the following error will appear and I can't install at all,,, even if I `sudo apt-get update` also..

```
samri@samri-Satellite-C55-C:~$ sudo apt-get install texlive-full
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucftmp' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Comment: What happens when you do `sudo dpkg --configure -a`  ?

Comment: following  massage will appear on the terminal .    package configuration window     with your system has UEFI  secure boot enabled. your UEFI secure boot is not compatible  with the use of third party driver.

Comment: I had a similar problem when I tried sudo apt install texlive-latex-full
however the following seemed to work for me:
sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra